# independence of two events (throw of coin)

Tags: probability

Throw $n$ times coin. Probablity of head is $p$. 
Find $n,p,k$ that $A$ and $B$ are independent.
$A$ - in first throw we had head
$B$ - we had exactly $k$ heads.

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each coin throw is independent, we know (from the binomial distribution) that:
$$
P(B) = \binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n-k}
$$

Given that the first throw is a head, the probability that we get exactly $k$ heads out of a total of $n$ coin throws is precisely the probability that we get exactly $k - 1$ heads from the remaining $n - 1$ coin throws. Thus:
$$
P(B \mid A) = \binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}(1 - p)^{n-k}
$$
But since $A$ and $B$ are independent, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
P(B) &= P(B \mid A) \\
\binom{n}{k}p^k(1 - p)^{n-k} &= \binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}(1 - p)^{n-k} \\
\frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}p &= \frac{(n - 1)!}{(k - 1)!(n - k)!}\\
\frac{n(n - 1)!}{k(k - 1)!}p &= \frac{(n - 1)!}{(k - 1)!}\\
\frac{n}{k}p &= 1 \\
p &= \frac{k}{n}
\end{align*}
So, for example, we could take $n = 6$, $p = 2/3$, and $k = 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Under the condition that $k$ of the $n$ tosses result in a head each of the $n$ tosses (also the first) has a chance of $\frac{k}{n}$ to result in a head:

$$P(A\mid B)=\frac{k}{n}$$

Secondly we know that $P(A)=p$, so we will have $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$ - i.e. independency - iff: $$\frac{k}{n}=p$$